# AS3 - Ball hitting Y coordinate

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a little app for school where you can controll a ball with the Acceleropmeter (for Smartphones) and I want that, if the ball reaches a certain Y coordinate, you lose and you go to another frame (where it says you have lost the game). 've done the ball and the code so far is this:

```
var fl_Accelerometer:Accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
fl_Accelerometer.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler);

function fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler(event:AccelerometerEvent):void
{
cBall.x -=  event.accelerationX * 40;
cBall.y +=  event.accelerationY * 40;
}

cBall.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);
function moveBall(evt:Event){

// this is to stop the ball when it tries to exit the sreen 

if(cBall.x > (480-cBall.width/2)){
    cBall.x = 480-cBall.width/2;
}
    // except for this, that stops the ball not if it touches the end of the screen, but if it reaches a certain Y coordinate
if(cBall.y > (780-cBall.width/2)){
   gotoAndStop(3);
}
if(cBall.x < (0+cBall.width/2)){
    cBall.x = 0+cBall.width/2;
}
if(cBall.y < (0+cBall.width/2)){
    cBall.y = 0+cBall.width/2;
}
}
```

Whenever I try the app, it says there is an error in the 32nd line (TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at ballApp_Scene1_fla::MainTimeline/moveBall()[ballApp_Scene1_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:32) Why? How can i fix this?

Comment: is cBall null? I don't see where you declare or intialize it anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

Since cball is the only object used in the moveBall-function, the null pointer exception means cBall was not yet initialized. Since this part is not shown there is no big help possible..

But maybe take a look at collision detection and the

- `BitmapData Class` and its method hittest :
  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#hitTest%28%29
- or `DisplayObject Class` offers hitTestPoint and hitTestObject
  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29
  If you can make different maps and object with image data and transparency it becomes easier to handle than hardcode each x and y coordinate to handle.

another one trying to do similar stuff:
[BitmapData Collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310005/bitmapdata-collision/10311688#10311688)